# Code snippet inside Highlight component displays in a long single line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code snippet inside Highlight component displays in a long single line.

How to add multiple line codes inside an Highlight component?

Comment: Have a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [react-highlight](https://github.com/akiran/react-highlight), the easiest way is probably to use `<br>`'s. It seems like using the `innerHTML` prop should also be an option, but from my (limited) testing, that functionality appears buggy.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Highlight from 'react-highlight';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Highlight language='javascript'>
          const varOnLine1 = "abc";<br/>
          const varOnLine2 = "def";<br/>
          const varOnLine3 = "ghi";
        </Highlight>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```